# Can I write C# code on Windows for an iPhone app, then copy the files to a Mac later?

Tags: c#, windows, macos

I don't own a Macbook at the moment, but plan on getting one in the next week. Would it be effective to write the C# code on my PC then copy the files to the Mac later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos

The new Dotnet Core framework is cross platform. So there shouldn't be a problem when you switch platforms.

If you are using the older dotnet platform for your iOs app, you could always use Mono to compile youre code.

http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Thanks for this, in terms of testing though I wouldn't actually be able to know if it works on an iPhone until I get a Mac though right? Sorry I'm new to app dev

Comment: Which framework do you use to make your iPhone app? I am pretty sure there are emulators available for it to test your applications.

Comment: Honestly I'm a Django/Python developer. But someone wants me to make apps for them so there's money involved. I haven't started yet or picked a framework. What would you recommend?

Comment: I am not really familiar in the iOS development branch, but I heard a lot about Xamarin https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035044668&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=CjwKEAjwse7JBRCJ576SqoD7lCkSJABF-bKuhIj8_WYsoy01eQgdCMDESfupnu6kpRP6WfOGrW1Q8xoCLjPw_wcB. However, if you are making a game I would recommend Unity3D

Comment: Yea I've looked into Xamarin, nope its not a game. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Apple has always traditionally required you have a Mac for building iPhone apps. Even if it's not native but using Cordova, yes, you still need XCode on a Mac to do the build. (I can't authoritatively comment on Xaramin and iPhone dev though.)

Answer (score 1):

C# is a language, if you use only C#, surely it will work. However you will probably use some framework. Also probably some UI. And then no, not that everything will work. There are Windows specific frameworks, and especially Windows specific ui kits like WPF and UWP, all of those can't be ported to Mac in any way.

Comment: Apparently the .NET framework is cross platform, how much will that help?

Comment: There are many flavors of .NET and in theory everything can be cross platform if it is implemented on other OS, but frequently it is not.

Comment: Okay, so I should just do the code in the framework and get the macbook and hope for the best? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I haven't fully understand how you will write the app. If you use Xamarin it will work.

Comment: I just want to get as much done on my PC before I buy the Mac, and okay thanks

Comment: One more thing. Since recently you can use Xamarin Player to code and test the apps for iPhone on the PC without a Mac (with some not so big limitations). Haven't tried it though.